# Raw access to SMS database file on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to get the SMS db file or any other way to get text messages in Windows Phone 8 using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is now way due to the security-idea and the sandboxes in WP8. You can see it [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api).